# Fire function after others complete javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

So I'm trying to run a function in JavaScript but I need all the other functions to run and finish before that one starts.  Here's the code (sorry, I know it's long but its the only way I can illustrate what's happening):

```
        getWeather();
        getAverage();


function getWeather() {
    $.getJSON("http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=" + lat + ",+" + lon + "&gflags=R&flags=J", function(data){
        zipCode = data.ResultSet.Results[0].postal;
        zipCode = zipCode.substring(0,5);
        WOEID = data.ResultSet.Results[0].woeid;
        getYahooWeather(WOEID);
        getWeatherbug(zipCode);
        getWeatherUnderground(zipCode);
        getWorldWeather(zipCode);
    });
}

function getYahooWeather(x) {
    var query = escape('select item from weather.forecast where woeid="'+x+'"');
    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + query + "&format=json";


    $.getJSON(url, function(data2){
        yahooTemp = data2.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
        $("#yahoo-weather p").replaceWith("<p>Weather from Yahoo! powered by The Weather Channel = "+yahooTemp+"&deg;F</p>");
    });
}

function getWeatherbug(x) {
    var url = "http://i.wxbug.net/REST/Direct/GetObs.ashx?api_key="+ weatherbugAPI + "&zip="+x+"&ht=t&ic=1&f=?";
    console.log(url);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data3) {
            //console.log(data3.temperature);
            wbTemp = data3.temperature;
            $("#wb-weather p").replaceWith("<p>Weather from WeatherBug = "+wbTemp+"&deg;F</p>");
        }
    });
}

function getWeatherUnderground(x) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/b87325296cd69fa8/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/"+x+".json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(parsed_json) {
        var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
        wuTemp = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
        $("#wu-weather p").replaceWith("<p>Weather from Weather Underground = "+wuTemp+"&deg;F</p>");
        }
    });
}

function getWorldWeather(x) {
    var url = "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?key="+wwKey+"&q="+x+"&fx=no&format=json";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data6) {
            wwTemp = data6.data.current_condition[0].temp_F;
            $("#ww-weather p").replaceWith("<p>Weather from World Weather Online = "+wwTemp+"&deg;F</p>");
        }
    });
}

function getAverage() {
    avTemp = wbTemp + wwTemp + yahooTemp + wuTemp;
    console.log(avTemp);
}
```

The problem I am having is whenever I run the getAverage function it will return NaN since the other functions haven't returned their data yet.

Is there a way to run a function after all of the previous functions returned their data?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't simply moving the call to appear just after getWorldWeather(zipCode); work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easier ways is to use an async library like `async` which can be found at https://github.com/caolan/async.  You can use the `parallel` function to run the getters in parallel and then return when all of them have finished.  The code ends up looking like:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 'one');
        }, 200);
    },
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 'two');
        }, 100);
    },
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // the results array will equal ['one','two'] even though
    // the second function had a shorter timeout.
});
```

The other way to do is to have a global variable that contains the number of callbacks that you are waiting for. Then in the callbacks for each of the weather getters, decrement the counter.  Before taking the average, just wait until the counter is at 0 (you can use setTimeout to wait a certain amount of time before checking again).

Answer (score 1):

To make it short: call `getAverage` from within the `getJSON` callback, i.e., right after you call `getWorldWeather(zipCode);`.

Comment: I don't think this will work because there is no way to tell which ajax call returns first. If getWorldWeather returns first, the average will be incorrect.

Comment: @Bill, you're absolutely right! Your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

There sure is. You're going to need to do what's called method passing, or making callbacks.

Here is an **untested** example on how you would go about it: http://jsfiddle.net/UDbeV/

Let me explain it in more detail.

```
var i = 0;
loopCount = function() {
    i++;
    if (i > 5) {
        getAverage();
    }
});
```

So we're creating a function called loopCount that stores a counter. Everytime its called, we increment its counter by 1.

Lets pass the callback to your methods:

```
    getYahooWeather(WOEID, callback);
    getWeatherbug(zipCode, callback);
    getWeatherUnderground(zipCode, callback);
    getWorldWeather(zipCode, callback);
    callback();
```

Now we have to change the functions to allow a second parameter:

```
function getYahooWeather(x, callback) { ...
```

And finally, at the end of each block, we want to call it:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data2) {
    yahooTemp = data2.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
    $("#yahoo-weather p").replaceWith("<p>Weather from Yahoo! powered by The Weather Channel = " + yahooTemp + "&deg;F</p>");
    callback();
});
```

The callback checks "if its been called enough times (ie: from how many calls you're doing before average), then calls getAverage();

There are probably more efficient ways to do this, but it's Monday :P Also, it is untested, so if you go with it, you'll need to probably hack it a bit. :o)